# Using experimental feature 'transaction'. use '--experimental' flag to enable the experimental features

Tags: ballerina

I used database transactions in my project as mentioned in https://ballerina.io/learn/by-guide/managing-database-transactions/ . My code is working but it shows  the error `using experimental feature 'transaction'. use '--experimental' flag to enable the experimental features` and

```
transaction with retries = 0{
}committed{
}aborted{
}
```

block is underlined with red color in VS Code Editor.

How to fix the error or is it an issue in VS Code plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for experimental features in VSCode plugin is disabled by default, that's why you seeing these red squiggly lines. You can enable experimental features by going to VSCode settings, under [ballerina], there should be a check box saying "Allow Experimental" check that and you should be good to go.

[image]